# Project Layout (on disk) in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, organization

What's the best way to manage the physical layout of a Visual Studio project on disk? I'm getting to the point where I have several folders but I can't really continue categorizing the way I am now. For example, I have several custom controls, but sometimes those controls have to do with application settings, so do they go into the Controls folder or Application Settings folder? I have many full-fledged forms that reside in the main source folder so that it's getting a bit daunting looking for the right source file.

Are there any tips anyone can offer on how they organize their medium-sized projects into folder hierarchies so they don't go insane trying to locate something in the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically organize my folders based on my namespaces. For example, classed in the namespace "Company.Project.DataAccess" would be stored in company/project/dataAccess directory.

I admit that this is still slightly painful to manage opening files. However, [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)'s "Go to type" feature has eliminated all of my searching in Solution Explorer.

Comment: Ah, so in my case I could simplify things by implementing a "User Interface\Forms, User Interface\Controls, User Interface\etc." type structure?

Comment: Exactly! I also end up having directories for Extensions, and sometimes Interfaces and Enums.

Answer (score 0):

This is the hierarchy I typically use in medium sized projects.

A solution file consisting of 3 projects:

1. The ASP.NET Web application project
2. A business logic project (housing the majority of my buslogic classes)
3. A database project (for housing my create scripts, stored procedures, etc.)

I'll have a forth project if I'm using custom WebControls. Within the Web app project, I'll have the usual folders such as *css*, *images*, *includes*, *scripts*, etc, as well as a folder for user controls if I'm using them. I almost always store my app settings in the Web.config.